# Help me parse this sentence

Tags: syntax, complements, free-relative-clauses

> Do you know what he is pretending that the broom is?

The *that-clause* within the *what-clause* is confusing me. Is this a grammatical sentence?

Comment: Does this make sense to you?: "He is pretending that the broom is his guitar." --I asked that for anyone who might answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed a grammatical sentence. It is confusing because it includes three separate clauses, with the second ‘embedded’ in the first and the third embedded in the second:

```
1 MAIN CLAUSE: Do you know X?
                           ⇓
  2 EMBEDDED:              He is pretending Y.
                                            ⇓
    3 EMBEDDED:                             The broom is X.
```

Two syntactical devices are employed to put these three clauses into the proper relationship in a single sentence. We work from the ‘bottom’ up, because each lower clause has to be restructured to fit into the next higher clause.

1. Clause 3 is recast employing the *complementizer*<sup>†</sup> ***that***. This transforms the clause into a form which allows it to act as the complement of the verb *PRETEND*, replacing **Y** in Clause 2.

   > He is pretending ***that*** the broom is X.
2. This expanded Clause 2 is recast employing the construction called a *free relative clause*<sup>‡</sup>. This construction replaces a clause constituent with an interrogative expression such as *what*, *who*, *where*, *how*, *when* and moves the interrogative to the ‘head’ of the clause. This permits the new construction to act as an NP (‘noun phrase’) constituent in a higher-order clause. In this particular case, the constituent you are interested in is ***X***, which you know to be a ‘thing’, so you replace it with *what*. Below I use an underscore, _, to indicate where the replaced constituent was originally.

   > ***what*** he is pretending that the broom is _.

Now you replace the ***X*** in Clause 1 with the transformed Clause 2, and you have your original sentence:

> Do you know ***what*** he is pretending that the broom is?

---

<sup>†</sup> In traditional grammar this is called a *subordinating conjunction*, and Clause 3 is said to be cast as a *subordinate clause*.

<sup>‡</sup> Free relative clauses are discussed at many places on ELL; click [free-relative-clauses](/questions/tagged/free-relative-clauses) for a list of related questions.